# conda activate on powershell

Tags: powershell, anaconda

Fresh install of conda. I'm trying to activate an environment (any environment) and I get the following

```
(base) PS C:\Users\AndrewBergan> conda activate test123

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\AndrewBergan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 138, in main
        return activator_main()
      File "C:\Users\AndrewBergan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 940, in main
        print(activator.execute(), end='')
      File "C:\Users\AndrewBergan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 173, in execute
        return getattr(self, self.command)()
      File "C:\Users\AndrewBergan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 150, in activate
        builder_result = self.build_activate(self.env_name_or_prefix)
      File "C:\Users\AndrewBergan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 275, in build_activate
        return self._build_activate_stack(env_name_or_prefix, False)
      File "C:\Users\AndrewBergan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 332, in _build_activate_stack
        self._replace_prefix_in_path(old_conda_prefix, prefix))
      File "C:\Users\AndrewBergan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 550, in _replace_prefix_in_path
        assert last_idx is not None
    AssertionError
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

Turns out for some reason `Continuum/anaconda3/Library/bin` did not get added to my path. Adding this fixed the problem.

Edit:
As noted in the comment below, other modifications to your path might be needed. I was able to determine what was missing from my path by adding a couple print statements to activate.py and comparing the output from the conda bash window and powershell.

Comment: I had the same issue and if your answer didn't work out for me, this path did: Continuum/anaconda3/bin
Can you edit your answer and suggest also that path for other users? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you can just update conda using following code

```
conda update -n base conda
```

Because conda 4.6.14 fixed this problem.

Answer (score 3):

conda start to support Powershell in version 4.6. upgrade your conda, then run this:

```
conda init
```

you should be fine then.

Answer (score 0):

I was too struggling with this trouble for a long time but couldn't find any solution online.
But I found it at last.
This is occurring because Windows PowerShell is not allowed to run local PowerShell scripts. It can be enabled in developer settings.

On windows 10

```
Settings > Update & Security > For developers >  Enable PowerShell to run local PowerShell scripts without signing in.
```

[see where to enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8j7d.png)